# interpretation of particle と followed by の

Tags: particles, particle-の

> 早｛はや｝くしないと、ヤツらとの最終｛さいしゅう｝聖戦｛せいせん｝の幕｛まく｝が切｛き｝って落｛お｝とされてしまうのだから……！

My doubt is specifically about the part ヤツらとの.

Several times I've come across the particle の being used right after another particle, but I haven't had any luck finding material covering this case.

The most likely to be accurate answers I've been given is that the の particle turns into a noun whatever comes before it - I'm familiar with that usage of の -  but with other particles just before の I have a hard time trying to make sense of everything.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing possession, as it usually does.  Hopefully this can clear it up.

```
ヤツらの最終聖戦 <- Their last holy war [with anyone]
ヤツらとの最終聖戦 <- [Our/Someone's] last holy war with them
```

You will see the combination often.

```
彼とのデート... A date with him
敵との戦い ... A fight with the enemy
```

I'm having a hard time finding any resources to explain it any further, unfortunately.  Hopefully that helped.

Answer (score 1):

の can be used as a nominalizer - eg. 読むのが怖い `reading [it] is scary` - but here it is simply the noun-joining particle as in 花子の髪 `Hanako's hair`.

> ヤツらとの最終聖戦の幕

The pattern here is `AとのBのC`. The first の works pretty much the same way as the second, it establishes a relation between the two noun (A and B), and (B and C), except that the first relation between A and B is specified further by the addition of the particle と.

Perhaps the best way to explain this is to consider what happens when we omit と. ヤツらの最終聖戦 simply means `their final holy war`, and for all we know, they might be waging war amongst themselves with no other parties involved.

と can be interpreted as "with". ヤツらと戦う, for example means `fight with (=against) them`, 君と出逢う means `to meet ["with"] you`.

Without の, ヤツらと最終聖戦(をする) sounds a bit strange and would mean `do the final holy war against them`. More importantly,  it can be interpreted only as a verbal action modified by ヤツらと, but not as a compound noun that can be compounded further. Ie., ✘ヤツらと最終聖戦の幕 is wrong [as a noun].

And that is why we need both と and の. ヤツらとの最終聖戦の幕 is a compound noun ready to be used in a larger sentence.

---

## Notes

(a)

Note that の does not always express an attributive (genitive) relation, but a more open one, eg. 課長の田中 does not mean `section-manager's Tanaka`.

(b)

の is used like this with some other particles and expressions. For example, in 愛についての感じ the relation between 愛 and 感じ is specified further - `a feeling regarding love`. On the other hand, in 愛の感じ the relation is left open.

More examples:

- ホストファミリーの**形態によってのそれぞれの違い**（メリット、デメリット）って何ですか？
- 幸福への近道
- **ご利用に関してのアンケート**のお願い
- 議会に対しての意見

Comment: Similar to the answer by @kiss-o-matic, but I'm at a part and began to write this on my phone before it was posted, so I might as well share it...

Comment: AとのBのC ＜ AとBとのC